# how to read special symbol using emdk

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, barcode, symbols, motorola-emdk

I use the Motorola EMDK sdk for .net to read the barcode, everything is ok except the **(** symbol and **)** symbol.

[image: http://goo.gl/7JkuYX]

[image: http://goo.gl/1w0vRi]

please see my code below:

```
MyReader = new Symbol.Barcode.Reader();
MyReader.Actions.Enable();
MyReader.Decoders.DisableAll();
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.Enabled = true;
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.MinimumLength = 2;
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.MaximumLength = 55;
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.EAN128 = true;
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.ISBT128 = true;
MyReader.Decoders.CODE128.Other128 = true;

MyReader.Decoders.SetEnabled(Symbol.Barcode.DecoderTypes.CODE128, true);
MyReaderData = new Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData(Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataTypes.Binary, Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);
MyEventHandler = new EventHandler(MyReader_ReadNotify);
MyReader.Actions.Enable();
```

Comment: The '(' and ')' are added to the human-readable part, they're not encoded in the barcode.  They're GS1-128 application identifiers.

Comment: thanks  charlesbridge

Answer (score 1):

Like charlesbridge said, the displayed information does not completely match the data encoded in the GS1 barcode.

The data inside the brackets is called an *application identifier* (AI). Each AI is followed by its data. For instance, (11)131011 means that the item was produced at October 11, 2013.

If you want to recreate the displayed string, your application would need to know the maximum length of each AI. If the data for an AI is shorter than its maximum length, it will be terminated by an 0x1d character (which *is* present in the decoded data, but won't be rendered on screen).

In your example only the serial number (21) has a variable length, but as it is the last AI in the barcode, the termination char is not needed.

See [the GS1 spec](http://www.gs1.org/docs/gsmp/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf) if you like reading, or [this list of application identifiers](http://www.databar-barcode.info/application-identifiers/) for a quick reference.

As for determining whether the barcode is a GS1 barcode, the `ReaderData` object contains a `Type` property which, at least on my device, would be one of the `RSS...` values.